# Validation Message not displaying below the TextBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am pretty new to `ASP.NET MVC`. I am working on this project where I have `Product Name` as a `TextBox`. I am attempting to perform `Validation` on this field. On clicking `Submit` button, I want to see whether the field is empty or not. If not, I want to print the error message below the field.

At present, on running the code, the validation seems to be working fine (as I tested it out by putting a sample `alert()`. However, I am not getting any text below the field. Where am I going wrong?

**.cshtml Code:**

```
<div class="input-group fg-float">
    <div class="fg-line">
        <input asp-for="ProductName" class="form-control" id="productName" name="productName" required />
        <label asp-for="ProductName" class="fg-label" for="productName">Product Name</label>
        <span asp-validation-for="ProductName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
@section Scripts{
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" })
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('form').validate({
            onfocusout: function (element) {
                this.element(element);
            },
            rules: {

            },
            messages: {
                productName: 'Enter Product Name'
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.input-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-error');
                $(element).closest('.input-group').addClass('has-success');
            }
        });
    })
</script>

}
```

Comment: Why in the world are you using `$('form').validate({` instead of just adding a `[Required]` attribute to you property so all this is handled out of the box (and delete your pointless `id="productName" name="productName" required` attributes from the textbox)

Comment: If I delete `$('form`).validate({` then how will I pass the custom error messages?

Comment: Its done automatically when you use `[Required(ErrorMessage = "my custom message")]public string ProductName { get; set; }`

Comment: Oh. So, you mean there is no need to use the `jQuery` function `.validate()` at all?

Comment: No. Just include the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in the view. You then get client and server side validation out of the box. And note that your attempt would have only given client side validation even if you did do it correctly (your selectors are incorrect) and anyone can by pass client side validation. you must always validate on the server

Comment: To add on to what @StephenMuecke posted above, these may already be bundled in your BundleConfig.cs. As jqueryval.